# Issues with typeahead & mention.js not showing in front of modal

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-typeahead

My problem right now is that the mention.js is showing behind the modals footer. How can I make it so that it floats ontop of the modal like twitters one.

[image: Modal]

CSS:

```
.modal-open .dropdown-menu {
  z-index: 2050;
}
.mention_name{
    font-size:12px;
    }
.mention_username{
    font-size:12px;
    color:#999;
    }
.mention_image{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    }
.active .mention_username{
    color:#fff;
    }
```

and I'm just using the regular basic bootstrap modal & mention.js

Answer (score 0):

You probably going to have to make a small edit to one of the bootstrap files. Open up bootstrap js (typeahead section) and then add a z-index of 9999:

```
this.$menu.css({
    top: pos.top + pos.height,
    left: pos.left,
    'z-index': 9999
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been fighting this a lot and found that one of the keys is making sure that the container div has the style

```
overflow : visible
```

From the screenshot, it appears that you might somehow have the style

```
overflow-y: scroll
```